# how to release the system libraries allocations in iphone(Frame work related)

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, memory-management, ios-4.2

i m facing big problem with system libraries allocations.
i didn't get any leaks from my application still so much allocations.i attached various screen shoots. in my application using custom picker which get all images from assert library.which are pick from picker showing images on scroll view.
[image]

its screen shot when my app with 35 images on scroll view.if again i pick images from custom picker  allocation increased.i am seeing object details its all related to frame Work allocations.not from my application  [image]
see the allocation object list response library is DYLD.[image]
[image]
its my leaks screen shot

**how can we release these allocations? please help me out ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because you have no leaks doesn’t mean you are managing memory correctly. What you have is what I call memory bloat — you are retaining it longer than you need to. (A leak is allocated memory with no references. Bloat is allocated memory that has a reference but should have none.)

http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/ will give you some good strategies for using Instruments to find them. (This is a very credible source, so far as I know he still works at Apple.)

Comment: will those allocations are autorelease?

Answer (score 2):

make sure your application has no leaked objects and they will also disappear in instruments. For sure its pointing to a system library but it is always a result of your bugs. Select one of them and open the right view. Probably it will show you the right code stack and the allocated line of code.
The other thing you can do: run the static analyzer Product->Analyze it will find all (at least most) your leaks ;)

Comment: Ya i m doing like that.but allocations are going very high and those response library is FrameWork Names

Comment: then put an autorelease pool around your memory intensive code and it will shrink down after the operation. The problem is that the objects don't get deallocated even if you call dealloc (don't ask me why). A NSAutoreleasePool will dealloc all objects which were allocated inside the pool.

Comment: You should never call dealloc yourself. Send release (or autorelease) instead.

Comment: @David Dunham sorry but where did I wrote he have to write dealloc? … ups sorry I found that, I meant "… even if you call release"